# UNION in 2 CUBES

Tags: union, mdx, pentaho, cube, mondrian

Is it possible to write UNION query of 2 cube in Mondrian MDX ?

For example:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Unit Sales],[Measures].[Store Sales]} ON COLUMNS,{[Product].members} ON ROWS
FROM [Sales_INDIA]
WHERE [Time].[1997].[Q2] 

UNION

SELECT {[Measures].[Unit Sales],[Measures].[Store Sales]} ON COLUMNS,[Product].members} ON ROWS
FROM [Sales_GERMANY]
WHERE [Time].[1997].[Q2]
```

ie. `UNION` between 2 cubes `Sales_INDIA` and `Sales_Germany`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNION in SSAS MDX query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815795/union-in-ssas-mdx-query)

Comment: Might be, but my understanding says technical implementation of Microsoft SSAS and Pentaho Mondrian (schema workbench) are different.