# UNION in SSAS MDX query

Tags: ssas, union, mdx, cube, msbi

Is it possible to write UNION in SSAS MDX query ?

For Example :

```
`SELECT
   {[Measures].[Sales Amount],[Measures].[Tax Amount]} ON COLUMNS,  
   {[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2002],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2003]} ON ROWS  
   FROM [Adventure_Workenter code heres_1]  
   WHERE ([Sales Territory].[Southwest])  

   UNION

   SELECT
   {[Measures].[Sales Amount],
   [Measures].[Tax Amount] } ON COLUMNS,
   {[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2002],
   [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2003]} ON ROWS  
   FROM [Adventure_Works_2]  
   WHERE ([Sales Territory].[Southwest])`
```

ie. UNION between 2 Cubes Adventure_Works_1 and Adventure_Works_2

Comment: Is the second cube in the same database? This is Multidimensional not Tabular right?

Comment: @GregGalloway I guess from a front end point of view there is no equivalent to Union in mdx? [but if they are on the same db then could a view be created on the server that combines the two?]

Comment: View comes to rescue. Thanks